# Apostrophe after University's name?

Tags: apostrophe

Is there an apostrophe after the name of my university?

I.e. is the apostrophe in this sentence correct?

> Of these 7 were postgraduate students at the University of Glasgow's School of Computing Science.

Comment: Not your question, but "Of these, seven were..." if that makes sense in context. Numbers below ten in a non-math context should be written out.

Comment: Yes if the sentence before that is "For this evaluation the author recruited 8 participants. 6 of them were male and 2 were female." then it makes sense ;)

Comment: The name of the department is "School of Computing Science". "University of Glasgow's" is added to clarify it. It could happen to be the case that the name of the deprtmant was "University of Glasgow School of Computing Science", in which case the apostrophe would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, the apostrophe is correct there.**  It's an example of a [*possessive apostrophe*](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/): we use *'s* after a noun or proper name to indicate possession.  For example,

- The boy's hat
- Mary's chair
- A house's door
- The University of Glasgow's School of Computing Science